# Unbinding live click on live element doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, click, live, unbind

I have following function to add elements to the page on the fly;

```
function modalConfirm (title, msgBody, btnOK, btnCancel) {
    element = '<div class="ui-modal-widget"><div class="confirm"><h2>'+title+'</h2><div>'+msgBody+'</div></div>';
    element += '<div class="button-panel" style="float:right; margin-top:-30px; margin-right:5px;">';
    element += '<a href="#" rel="closeModal">'+btnCancel+'</a>';
    element += '<a href="#" rel="confirmModal">'+btnOK+'</a>';
    element += '</div></div>';
    // OPEN MODAL WINDOW
```

I'm calling the function above when `$('a.checkData')` is clicked.

**PROBLEM**

---

Everything seems working fine except, if I close the opened modal window by clicking `$('a[rel=closeModal]')` more than once and after that few times click `$('a[rel=confirmModal]')` it is doing the same actions as many times as I clicked `$('a[rel=closeModal]')`.

Example;

```
$('a[rel=closeModal]').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// CLOSE MODAL BOX
});

$('a[rel=confirmModal]').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
console.log('Modal Is Confirmed');
});
```

Consider the code above. When `$('a.checkData')` is clicked and user clicks `$('a[rel=closeModal]')` **5 times** before clicking `$('a[rel=confirmModal]')`. It will write  **5 times** `Modal Is Confirmed` **for 1 click**. If user clicks `$('a[rel=closeModal]')` 10 times before clicking `$('a[rel=confirmModal]')`. It will write  10 times `Modal Is Confirmed`.

I will be glad if you could help me out with this problem. I tried to add `$('a[rel=confirmModal]').unbind('click');` literally everywhere (inside the function, before calling the function, after calling the function just before / after / inside of the `$('a[rel=confirmModal]').live('click',function(){});` without any success.

Thank you for your time and concern in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider using [jQuery delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [jQuery undelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/)

This is very similar to live however you can choose whether or not to bind to the document body or to a relative parent of the future added element.

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot about it. I had similar problem in the past and I had to use it once before as well. No wounder why people say **you don't use it, you lose it** (: Thanks a lot for the fast reply.